trap and signals in bash when process is in the background
I have the following script
_term () {
  touch hi.txt
}
trap '_term' SIGINT SIGTERM
tail -F test.sh

I execute ./test.sh and I press ctr+c and the file is created as expected.
I execute ./test.sh & and I execute kill -SIGINT  then nothing happens.
Can somebody explain me why that is? And what to change for it to work as expected.
What I have tried:

Different statements like "echo hi" or "exit 0". All seem to not be executed.
Diffeent signals
sleep 9000 instead of tail -F
killing the "tail -F" XD Then surprise the signal handler is executed as expected.
fg and then ctr+c works flawlessly
tail -F test.sh & wait works but why


If you want to make the handler happen immediately, change your last line to tail -F test.sh & wait. Mind, I'd also want to have the signal handler explicitly kill the copy of tail.

Yes that works. But why :D ?

Strace shows the programm receives the signal:
[pid   335] --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=172, si_uid=1000} ---[pid   335] rt_sigreturn({mask=[CHLD]}) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)

Handler seems to be registered as far as I can tell rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x563b73dcb690, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe414fd7dd0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fe414fd7dd0}, 8) = 0

trap _term EXIT may do you better.

trap _term EXIT works perfectly. What's the difference?

foo & && wait is invalid syntax. I meant what I said when I suggested foo & wait with no added &&. As for the "why", does the linked duplicate not explain it adequately?

I did it in two lines. That works. Yes what I wrote might not be valid syntax

Did your trap succeed? Do a trap '_term' SIGINT SIGTERM || echo "trap handler can not be set up" 1>&2
